# openstack error CRITICAL keystone [-] Unhandled error: KeyError: 'connection'

Tags: openstack

Hi I am new to `Openstack` , while installing I am getting an error , which I have given below.

> init__
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/migrate/versioning/repository.py:83}}
>
> - CRITICAL keystone [-] Unhandled error: KeyError: 'connection'
>
> ERROR keystone Traceback (most recent call last):

Please help me in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an error while you are configuring the database in `keystone` service installation. Try to cross check once your database credentials are given correct or not in `/etc/keystone/keystone.conf`

For example:

```
[database]
# ...
connection = mysql+pymysql://keystone:KEYSTONE_DBPASS@controller/keystone
```